# mixing parallelism and async within wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, mvvm-light

I need to **mix** `parallelism` and `async`  concepts in my WPF startup code :

```
 protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) 
 {
     AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
     currentDomain.UnhandledException += currentDomain_UnhandledException;
     ViewModelLocator locator = (ViewModelLocator)App.Current.Resources["Locator"];
     SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
     SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IndexViewModel>();
     Func<Task> fsignHandler = async () => { await Task.Run(() => { SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Fiche_SignaletiqueViewModel>(); Debug.WriteLine("fsign loaded"); }); };
     Func<Task> formationHandler = async () => { await  Task.Run(() => { SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<FormationsViewModel>(); }); };
     await Task.WhenAll(fsignHandler(), formationHandler());
}
```

I get these problems :

1. In the output window I don't get the message `fsign loaded`.
2. I use `MVVM light` with its IoC `SimpleIOC`: when I navigated to the menu `Fiche_Signaletique` (with `Fiche_SignaletiqueViewModel` as view model) the class **Fiche_SignaletiqueViewModel** will be instanciated which indicates that `fsignHandler` was never be executed !!!!

I need to know :

- What are the reasons of these problems?
- What are the errors I commited?
- How can I fix my code?

Comment: You're `new`ing up your `Task` instances but never starting them (ergo, they never complete). Use `Task.Run` instead.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy ok but the execution of the tasks become sync !!

Comment: @LamloumiAfif: It shouldn't...

Comment: @JonSkeet plz see my edit , with this code the interface is blocked until the execution of all tasks will be finished

Comment: Again, it shouldn't be (if the two calls to `GetInstance` that you're executing synchronously execute quickly). It would really help at this point if you could put together a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. Ideally, take SimpleIOC and MVVM Light out of the picture - simplify it as far as possible.